# AutoSize height for rows In Apache.Poi 3.15

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have to make a report but the content is bigger than the cell space and I want to autofit the cell height using wrapText from Apache.Poi

I'm experiencing an issue with applying the 'wrap text' feature correctly when using the sheet.addMergedRegion method with a for loop for parameter passing. I have defined a headerCellStyle and set the wrapText property to true along with other formatting options. However, the text does not wrap as expected. Here's the relevant code:

```
CellStyle headerCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
            headerCellStyle.setFont(font);
            headerCellStyle.setWrapText(true);
            headerCellStyle.setAlignment(HorizontalAlignment.CENTER);
            headerCellStyle.setBorderLeft(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            headerCellStyle.setBorderRight(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            headerCellStyle.setBorderTop(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);
            headerCellStyle.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.MEDIUM);

            Row rowHeader = sheet.createRow(12);
            Cell cellHeader=null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                cellHeader = rowHeader.createCell((i*10) + 1);
                cellHeader.setCellValue(listaCabecera.get(i));
                cellHeader.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle);
                sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(12, 12, (i*10)+1, (i*10)+10));
            }
```

However, if I explicitly specify the range for each sheet.addMergedRegion call, the wrapText feature works correctly. For example:

```
            Row rowHeader = sheet.createRow(12);
            Cell cellHeader=null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                cellHeader = rowHeader.createCell((i*10) + 1);
                cellHeader.setCellValue(listaCabecera.get(i));
                cellHeader.setCellStyle(headerCellStyle); // Aplica el estilo a cada celda creada
                if(i==0) {
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(12, 12, 1, 10));
                }
                if(i==1) {
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(12, 12, 11, 20));
                }
                if(i==2) {
                    sheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(12, 12, 21, 30));
                }
            }
```

Why is the wrapText not working when using the sheet.addMergedRegion method within a for loop? Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue? Thank you!"